# twilio REST api question for making calls

Tags: php, rest, twilio

A

Right now I have sequential dialing being done using Dial verb but now I want my application to do the calling for which the dial verb does not work and thus I need the REST api.....

I can't figure out how to do this, I am new to REST. Does using a timeout make it skip lines? If timeout works then perhaps I can make this work but other than that I really have no ideas..

Also, how can I get the status of the call in REST?

Lets say my code looks like this, how would I change it to get the status of the call and set a timeout on the call?

```
<?php
// Include the Twilio PHP library
require 'Services/Twilio.php';
// Twilio REST API version
$version = "2010-04-01";
// Set our Account SID and AuthToken
$sid = 'AC123';
$token = 'abcd';
// A phone number you have previously validated with Twilio
$phonenumber = '4151234567';
// Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);
try {
// Initiate a new outbound call
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
$phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
'5101234567', // The number of the phone receiving call
'http://demo.twilio.com/welcom/voice/'
);
echo 'Started call: ' . $call->sid;
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: The <Dail at the top is hiding part of your question. Try changing it to just dial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [PHP helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install):

```
<?php
// Include the Twilio PHP library
require 'Services/Twilio.php';
// Twilio REST API version
$version = "2010-04-01";
// Set our Account SID and AuthToken
$sid = 'AC123';
$token = 'abcd';
// A phone number you have previously validated with Twilio
$phonenumber = '4151234567';
// Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);
try {
// Initiate a new outbound call
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
$phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
'5101234567', // The number of the phone receiving call
'http://demo.twilio.com/welcom/voice/',
array('timeout'=>'15','ifmachine'=>'hangup','status_callback'=>'yourNextNumberHandler.php')
);
echo 'Started call: ' . $call->sid;
echo 'The status of the call is '.$call->status;
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

This code is based on the documentation in https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blame/master/docs/api/rest.rst

So I did a couple things:

1. Added an array of parameters to the outgoing call in order to:

   - set the timeout (note: may not be string '15', if this does not work
     try 15 as a number)
   - determine what to do if a machine answers (in this case I chose to
     hang up)
   - determine what to do when the call ends (in this case Twilio requests `'yourNextNumberHandler.php'` to proccess the next numbers)
2. On the bottom we have `echo 'The status of the call is '.$call->status;` which should give you an out put in one of the following set`QUEUED,RINGING,IN-PROGRESS, COMPLETED,FAILED,BUSY,or NO_ANSWER`
   **another** way to process multiple calls would be to do a check like

   $i=0;
   $myPhoneList = array('14162351836','16472871987',18003984785');
   if ($call->status == 'COMPLETED'){
      //Place a new call to number $myPhoneList[$i++];
   }

instead of using the callback `'yourNextNumberHandler.php'` of `status_callback` parameter

I haven't used twilio that much, but I hope this helps

Comment: that isnt what I need...if i need to check the status of the call, how would I POST the StatusCallback? I already know the format of response is xml...Are you familair with Twilio?

Comment: I replaced my calling info with the code you provided and the code doesn't work as in, it doesnt make a call to the number or display the xml even.

Comment: It did call but the timeout did not work am I suppose to process the timeout once its passed to yournextnumber.php? The status isn't displaying anything but QUEUED. :( T_T

Comment: i think the `echo 'The status of the call is '.$call->status;` is being processed too early a.k.a before the call is actually initiated (thus queued ). try removing `,'ifmachine'=>'hangup','status_callback'=>'yourNextNumberHandler.php'` from the param list before anything else though